# Use Outlook to search for messages from anyone in a group?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

Is it possible to search for Outlook messages from everyone in a specific group?

For instance there might be some department (group oh people with a email group) that sends me emails and I'd like to find any messages from any of them that might have sent me a message.

Is that possible?

Comment: Open Search and then go to Search Tools, Advanced Find.  If Group is in Contacts, you can use the Criteria function to find the Group.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, it seems outlook doesn’t support to search emails from people in a group directly. There isn’t a choice which is the member of:

The worst thing is maybe you need to search emails for the users in the group one by one.

But you can still find if there is anything you need in the advanced search.

Update: You can create a search folder to search mail from specific people.

[image: picutre1]

Select the group you want to search.

Then search the user on the search bar.

[image]

Comment: If the issue has been solved. please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.

Comment: Hi, how's everything going now ?

Comment: Hi. Please do not forget to mark the helpful reply as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any update about this issue?